# How to get the src of the Uploaded Image?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I have a File Upload Control. Once an image uploaded, I would like to access to the Id of the uploaded image's src within javascript and store it in a server side control or database.
Spent two days on it. Please help!

Comment: javascrip runs on the client side... if your img is already on the server why use javascript ?

Comment: You have to pass the ID from the server side to JavaScript via injecting some JavaScript into the HTML or via AJAX or similar technology.

Comment: What it is - When the client uploads an image the page source look like: <div><img src="jljsdlsdfmşm"></div>. What I intend to do is get the value of the src and send it to server side. I used getElementById in javascript. But didn't work.

Comment: because your img have no id attribute... get the src attribute with jquery assuming you have only one img element: $("img").prop("src"); set an id or get the element by the parents

Comment: Here is javascript: TextBox with the id of txtCODE will keep the value of the image's src. <script type="text/javascript">
       function txtBind() {
           document.getElementById('<%=txtCODE.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById("imgLogo").value;
       }
   </script>. Textbox gets the value "undefined"